# Retain variables for missing value

Tags: sas

Should be an easy question. I have a dataset like this:

```
id mtna
1  .
2  .
3  1.7
4  .
5  .
6  5.2
7  9.6
8  .
9  .
10 .
```

And I want something like this:

```
id mtna 
1 . 
2 . 
3 1.7 
4 1.7 
5 1.7 
6 5.2 
7 9.6 
8 9.6 
9 9.6 
10 9.6
```

Basically just retain the pervious observation when there is a missing value. 
So I try something like this:

```
data check; set check; 
retain lag_mtna; 
lag_mtna=lag1(mtna); 
if mtna=. then mtna=lag_mtna; 
run;
```

But then it turns out like this:

```
id mtna 
1 . 
2 . 
3 1.7 
4 1.7 
5 . 
6 5.2 
7 9.6 
8 9.6 
9 . 
10 .
```

How can I retain all those values? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to retain variable that is coming from dataset.
Adding few tricks, it could be like this:

```
data check;
set check (rename=(mtna=orig_mtna));
retain mtna;
mtna=coalesce(orig_mtna, mtna);
drop orig_mtna;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for any attention. I solve it via a simple way.

```
data check; set check;
retain mtna_new mtna;
if mtna ne . then mtna_new=mtna;
run;
```

Comment: Don't "retain" mtna; it has no effect because it's value comes from your data set "check".  Otherwise fine.