# An efficient way to Copying values in subsequent records - SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that is grouped by category variables in the source data. For example:

```
Bar  | Foo1
     | Foo2
     | Foo3
Bar2 | Foo4
     | Foo5
     | Foo6
```

After I import the source data, the above would result in the first Variable (Parent) being populated on Record 1 but not #2 and #3. I would like to copy the parent variable's value into record 2 and 3. Thus my output would look more like this:

```
Bar  | Foo1
Bar  | Foo2
Bar  | Foo3 
Bar2 | Foo4
Bar2 | Foo5
Bar2 | Foo6
```

I tried using a "LAG" function, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
if PARENT ~= "" then do;
   PARENT = PARENT;
end;
else do;
   PARENT = LAG(PARENT);
end;
```

Comment: `retain` is one way to solve this. Check if [this retain question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873284/retain-variables-for-missing-value) can help you.

Comment: `lag()` strikes again...

Comment: I think this has now gotten better answers than that one, so I'll close as duplicate in this direction.  In the future feel free to flag to close as duplicate - in particular, if someone's already done so and it's right, feel free to put the better answers on the duplicate as I'll close it in that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retain the non-missing value and apply it to any missing values, e.g.

```
data want ;
  set have ;

  length last $10. ;
  retain last '' ;

  if not missing(PARENT) then last = PARENT ;
  else PARENT = last ;

  drop last ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The lag function returns the last value that was passed to it when it was called, not the value that was last output.

You could do something like the following:

```
data want;
    set have;
    length last_parent $256;
    retain last_parent;

    if parent = "" then parent = last_parent;
    else last_parent = parent;

    drop last_parent;
run;
```

You would need to set the length of last_parent to the same length as parent to make sure nothing gets cut off.

Comment: @LeoGreyz thank you. This is the solution. Unfortunately another similar answer came in a few seconds ahead of yours, so I had to accept that as the "Accepted Answer".

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to add a dummy variable, then trick SAS by using Update statement.

```
data have;
infile cards dlm='|';
    input (var1 var2) (:$8.);
    retain idx 1;
    cards;
Bar  | Foo1
     | Foo2     
     | Foo3
Bar2 | Foo4
     | Foo5
     | Foo6
     ;

data want;
    update have (obs=0) have;
    by idx;
    output;
    drop idx;
run;
```