# copy observation of one variable down from first until last of another variable

Tags: sas

Ok, so I have a customer id and a session id.  For the first of multiple duplicate session id's I have a customer id, but for the subsequent ones I don't.  I need to copy the customer id that I have down to the other blanks that are in the same session.  My attempt at a code is as follows:

```
proc sort data=weblogsnew1;
by session_id descending customer_id;
run;

data weblogsnew2;
set weblogsnew1;
by session_id descending customer_id;
if first.session_id then do until(last.session_id);
customer_id=first.customer_id;
end;
run;
```

This code spins endlessly but nothing happens?  I probably need to do some kind of DOW loop, but I am a relative beginner and it confuses me, so I was hoping that someone could give me some sort of direction.

Session_id  .............    Customer_id
1442103120308   ..... f8d63284bc0b463a93c588fef719bee0
1442103120308   ..... 0
1442103120308   ..... 0
1442103120308   ..... 0
1442103120308   ..... 0
1442103120308   ..... 0
1442103120308   ..... 0
1442103202937   ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937   ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937   ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937   ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937   ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937   ..... 0
1442103202937   ..... 0
1442103202937   ..... 0
1442103202937   ..... 0
1442103202937   ..... 0
1442103202937   ..... 0
1424466798849   ..... 0
1424466798849   ..... 0
1424466798849   ..... 0

In some cases I only have 0's, so just using a retain statement won't work.

Because I'm terrible at formatting the dots are there just to break the two columns up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An efficient way to Copying values in subsequent records - SAS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642482/an-efficient-way-to-copying-values-in-subsequent-records-sas)

Comment: From what I understand you don't need a loop, you need a RETAIN. If this isn't correct, please post some sample data to help clarify your question.

Comment: The retain statement in the link @Reeza sent does not work because in some cases there is never a customer_id (ie only 0's), and in that case the previous customer_id gets retained down to the new session.  

I need the customer_id to be determined by the session_id, including a situation where they are all 0's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that something like this would work:

```
data session;
   infile cards firstobs=2;
   input session_id :$13. dots $ Customer_id :$32.;
   drop dots;
   cards;
Session_id ............. Customer_id
1442103120308 ..... f8d63284bc0b463a93c588fef719bee0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937 ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937 ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937 ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937 ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 0
1424466798849 ..... 0
1424466798849 ..... 0
1424466798849 ..... 0
;;;;
   run;

data want;
set session(rename=customer_id=old_customer_id);
by session_id notsorted;
retain customer_id;
if first.session_id then customer_id=old_customer_id;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is endless loop unless there happens to be only one session_id observation.

```
if first.session_id then do until(last.session_id);
customer_id=first.customer_id;
end;
```

A DOW has the SET inside the DO UNTIL(LAST.; END; code block.

It would be easier for me to help if you show some sample data.

Also first.customer_id is a Boolean not the value of customer_id.

Comment: I added a sample in my original comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I might do it using a DOW, for LOCF.

Fixed omitted BY statement and added call missing.

```
data session;
   infile cards firstobs=2;
   input session_id :$13. dots $ Customer_id :$32.;
   drop dots;
   cards;
Session_id ............. Customer_id
1442103120308 ..... f8d63284bc0b463a93c588fef719bee0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103120308 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937 ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937 ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937 ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937 ..... 4f13e0aebdda4811834285efe9543446
1442103202937 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 0
1442103202937 ..... 0
1424466798849 ..... 0
1424466798849 ..... 0
1424466798849 ..... 0
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data locf;
   if 0 then set session;
   do until(last.session_id);
      set session(rename=(Customer_id=xcust));
      by session_id notsorted;
      if xcust ne '0' then Customer_id = xcust;
      output;
      end;
   call missing(of Customer_id);
   drop xcust;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: This works and doesn't work.  I should have included in my original dataset I showed, there are some situations where a the customer id attached to a session id is all 0's.  In this situation, the code you wrote retains the last known customer id and gives it to all the 0's. I have now included a few 0 only observations in the dataset in my original question.

Comment: It should be good now.  I omitted the all important BY statement and we also need CALL MISSING for CUSTOMER_ID because I copied it from session with IF 0 then set...